# How to integrate two web template theme on React single project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a new project on React JS. I decide to use a HTML & CSS free theme template for my project. I found the two best theme templates for the frontend (visible to the public) and the admin panel (CMS). I add both the css and js script link to my React project. When I start the project, the design of the frontend becomes buggy. I cannot get the actual design of the template. It has completely changed my design. When I commented the admin theme css & js, then i get actual output of the frontend and vice versa. If I activate css & js for both the frontend and the admin then the design get buggy. Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this issue?

**index.html**

**Frontend CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/socicon/css/socicon.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/unicore/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/dropdown-menu/style.light.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/mob-slider/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/mob/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css" />
```

**Frontend JS**

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/smooth-scroll/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/bootstrap-carousel-swipe/bootstrap-carousel-swipe.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/unicore/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/dropdown-menu/script.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/frontend/assets/formoid/formoid.min.js"></script>
```

**Backend CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/css/style.css" />
```

**Backend JS**

```
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/vendors/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/js/off-canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/js/hoverable-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/js/misc.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/backend/assets/js/todolist.js"></script>
```

Can anyone provide me the solution for this? How can i manage both template theme for my single project?

Comment: you can try CSS prefixing.

Comment: Can you please explain it more?  Actually i am learning MERN technology and not so familiar with CSS & HTML.

Comment: Normally for frontend of larger react projects you use a resource bundler like `webpack`, that minimizes the data loaded and can preprocess CSS, javascript, images and other resources in many useful ways. One of the ways it can do is to add a prefix to declarations in CSS so that two different stylesheets do not interfer with each other and automatically change the names of the classNames in your React JSX files. Sadly at least `webpack` haa many options so it takes some time to learn it.

Comment: and I would appreciate if you could share some sites where I can find good themes.